# How to override core helper in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, overrides, helper, preference

I writed a preference for class Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image but i got this error:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 4 passed to
>   Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor::__construct() must be
>   an Instance of Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image, instance of
>   RMI\ImageCDN\Helper\Image given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 107 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\var\generation\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor.php
>   on line 11

If preference is not a good way to override a helper in core , what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way, but you have to extend the original helper, because all classes that use it, actually expect an instance of the original helper (or a derived class)

Comment: The preference way got a error Recoverable Error: Argument 4 passed to  ...
It seems magento dose not inject my preference class instead original class in all constructors in core because the error point that :
Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor constructor must be an Instance of Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image, instance of RMI\ImageCDN\Helper\Image, the "RMI\ImageCDN\Helper\Image " is my preference class

Comment: the error message says, that the constructor of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor` expects an instance of the original class (`Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`), but, because of your preference, an instance of your new helper class is injected. Since the constructor expects `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`, you have to extend your class from it.

Comment: sound is like good, I did
mypreference(RMI\ImageCDN\Helper\Image) extends Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image but new error happend:
Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ImageFactory, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\RMI\ImageCDN\Helper\Image.php on line 145 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php on line 136

Comment: you have to call the original constructor with the original arguments (like the error states) of course. However, this is a new problem so please add a new question for this

Comment: OK , Thank u for your help, I will ask a new question.